# Showing $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $f:A\to B$ is a ring homomorphism, then I want to show that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal of $A$, given that $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $B$.

Say $ab\in f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$. Then $f(ab)\in \mathfrak{p}$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$, so since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$. But then we can consider $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})\supseteq f^{-1}(f(a))\ni a$ and $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})\supseteq f^{-1}(f(b))\ni b$ in which case $a$ or $b$ is in $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$.

Is this okay?

Secondly. Why does one denote $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}\cap A$. This is 'literally' incorrect isn't it? This is notation of Matsumura.

Comment: $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})=\mathfrak{p}\cap A$ is correct when $A$ is a subring of $B$, which is a frequent special case.

Comment: On your second point, the notation would make "literal sense" if $f$ were an inclusion of $A$ into an overring $B$.  Is it perhaps a special case in the place you found that equation?

Comment: @hardmath That does justify it. However, it isn't used in any such context here.

It occurs on the first page of Matsumura, for an arbitrary ring hom $f:A\to B$. It also occurs on the conventions page, and I quote: "If $F:A\to B$ is a homomorphism of rings and if $I$ is an ideal of $B$, then the ideal $f^{-1}(I)$ is denoted by $I\cap A$."

Comment: @hardmath It's an "abuse of notation" that some commutative algebraists use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach: $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$
is the kernel of the composition of the homomorphisms $f:A\to B$ and $\pi:B\to B/\mathfrak{p}$. The image of $\pi\circ f$ is a subring of
$B/\mathfrak{p}$, which is an integral domain, and so
the image of $\pi\circ f$ is an integral domain. So the kernel
of $\pi\circ f$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and this would make me very happy if there is a connection. Is $B/\mathfrak{p}$ related to the fraction field $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ by any chance (maybe under some conditions)

Comment: @Fredrieck $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ is the field of fractions of the integral domain $B/\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I confused myself (and got ahead of myself), and thought I saw a connection to $$R\to R/\mathfrak{p} \to \kappa(\mathfrak{p})$$
(for functions on $\text{Spec}(R)$)

Comment: @Fredrieck The localization of $B$ is $B_\mathfrak{p} = \{ \frac{u}{v}, u,v \in B, v \not\in \mathfrak{p}\}$. It has a unique prime and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p} B_\mathfrak{p}$ and $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) = B_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p} B_\mathfrak{p} = \text{Frac}(B/\mathfrak{p})$

Answer (score 0):

You should prove that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)$ is an ideal of $A$. If you have already shown it, you should mention it, at least.

Comment: I suppose for this, the only hard part is showing that $x\in f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ and $r\in A$ gives us $rx\in f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$. Then we consider $f(x)\in \mathfrak{p}$ which is an ideal. Then $f(r)\in B$ and $B\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{p}$ and hence $f(r)\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{p}$, meaning $f(r)f(x)=f(rx)\in\mathfrak{p}$ and thus $f^{-1}(f(rx))\subset f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) \implies rx\in f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$